# jQuery Drawing Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, canvas, javascript

Camarades,

You'd know me identify good libraries (preferably in jQuery) to work with "Canvas" and drawings in javascript / html. I want to make my page more interesting, especially in some registries (registry of cars) and would like to draw a car and be able to go changing the number of wheels for example.

Many thanks for any help.
Success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery paint plugin that does exactly what you're looking for: http://www.websanova.com/plugins/websanova/paint